# alert box shown when nothing changes are done in form

Tags: jquery, html, forms, jquery-dirtyforms

when nothing changes is being done in form on which this plugin used and when user exits form it still shows alert box of unsaved changes .so please tell me how to fix this issue so that its alert box only apears when change is being done in the forms .THis is link of that plugin

https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms

i have used it by using id of particular form

```
 $('business-form').dirtyForms();
```

Comment: If you are selecting an element by its `id`, then you have to do something like `$('#id-of-the-element').whatever()`. Just add a `#`

Comment: done but still same issue without making any changes in the form it shows alert box for save changes when i reload the form or exit it.

Comment: Have you tried turning on debugging and checking the console? `$.DirtyForms.debug = true;`

Comment: yes i have tried this still it is showing alert of unsaved changes when i reload or exit form without making any changes.@Owlvark

Comment: I suspect another plugin is interfering. Try disabling plugins until the problem goes away. Perhaps look for something that alters the focus of elements like a placeholder plugin.

Comment: browser i am using is latest version which supports placeholder for **input** and **text** elements thats why placeholder plugin not needed.Any other suggestion which resolve this issue because i am using 3 plugins as your suspect is right. @Owlvark

Comment: any other suggestion for this issue@Owlvark

Answer (score 0):

By default, Dirty Forms [attaches event handlers to most anchor tags on the page](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#default-anchor-ignoring-behavior), and an assumption is made that if one of them is clicked, the user is attempting to navigate from the page.

Some 3rd party widgets use anchor tags in their design. If any of them are causing problematic behavior, you need to ignore them manually by setting the `$.DirtyForms.ignoreSelector` or adding the `ignoreClass` to either every anchor within the element or a parent container they are hosted in.

See [Ignoring Things](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#ignoring-things) for more information.

You can view the markup of the widgets using a tool such as [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), so you can work out exactly how to ignore anchor tags.